# How to loop despatch_after

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want to loop dispatch_after for looping showing images like this:

```
   while isRunning {
        let delay = Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * settings.delay)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.showNextImage()
            })
        })
    }
```

It supposed to call `showNextImage` every `delay` seconds. But it stucks in infinite loop without showing images. I dont know how to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop is dispatching infinite dispatch_after because isRunning is yes and loop is not waiting , better to put some count (i<10) or use NSTimer to certain condition then invalidate.

```
if (self.stimerShowNextImage.isValid) {

        [self.stimerShowNextImage invalidate];
        self.stimerShowNextImage = nil;

    }
    self.stimerShowNextImage = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5
                                                                 target: self
                                                               selector: @selector(showNextImage)
                                                               userInfo: nil
                                                                repeats: YES];
```

Above is the timerCode with 5 second delay , in ViewWillDisapper you need to invalidate it , Also before scheduling timer you need to check its not already running.

Comment: Please write how to use NSTimer in this case for infinite loop?

Comment: @AndreyM. whats the logic to show the images self.showNextImage , is there any condition till you want to show them

Answer (score -1):

Look in your code dispatch_after already running in main thread. And again inside main thread using. i mean not need.
when it is need means if u r using other than main thread outside and after u r using uielements, that time use main thread inside.